# Как определить, существует ли свойство в интерфейсе

Tags: typescript

Как динамически определить, существует ли свойство в интерфейсе. Для объекта возможно использовать hasOwnProperty, а для интерфейса?

```
class Работа_с_БД {
  сохранено_в_БД: boolean;
  есть_изменения: boolean;
  сохранить() {...}
}

interface IДокумент {
  название: string;
  дата_создания: дата;
}

class Документ extends Работа_с_БД  implements IДокумент {
...
}
```

При реализации метода сохранить, для передачи через рест на бэк, хотелось бы не учитывать свойства родительского объекта

Comment: приведи пример для чего тебе это может понадобиться?

Comment: Есть класс родитель и класс потомок. Потомок реализует интерфейс. Возникла необходимость понимания, где определено свойство, в родителе или потомке.

Comment: добавь код для твоего примера в вопрос.  Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit]. А какая разница где определено свойство?

Comment: _хотелось бы не учитывать свойства родительского объекта_ - О каком объекте тут речь? Ты хочешь, чтобы сериализованы были только поля _название_ и *дата_создания*? Их в любом случае нужно будет вручную прописывать

Comment: Надеялся, что можно как-то не вручную...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что происходит в методе _сохранить_ и какой результат ожидается.

Comment: В методе сохранить собираю все свойства, определенные в интерфейсе IДокумент и отправляю их в бек, для записи в БД, если все нормально, то   указываю, что сохранено_в_БД=true. Я в SPA на Vue пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде ORM на браузере.

Comment: то есть по сути ты хочешь получить `keys of IДокумент`? В виде массива строк, например?

Comment: именно это и хотелось получить

Comment: тогда это весьма не тривиально: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43922291/2881286

Comment: для понимания: "TS - это просто JSDoc". Немного упрощенно, но суть такова. да есть такая штука как reflect metadata, но оно вам не упростит жизнь

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку, действительно, не шибко просто выходит, попробую что-нибудь архитектурно поменять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В динамике нет interface. typeScipt Interface в javaScript переводится ни во что.